# Interface to allow the user to type/input text in a-frame (headset)

Tags: aframe

I'm working on an a-frame project that would require the user to write a line of text in an input field. 
Of course in the browser, this is possible to achieve with the keyboard, but I don't know how I would go about doing this if the user views the a-frame virtual reality with a headset.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [AFrame GUI Component](https://rdub80.github.io/aframe-gui/) 
There is a [keyboard](https://rdub80.github.io/aframe-gui/examples/casestudy_keyboard.html) mapped for gaze/fuze input

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the `<a-keyboard>` primitive that's part of the aframe-material collection:

https://github.com/etiennepinchon/aframe-material#-a-keyboard-%EF%B8%8F